# Difference between photorec and testdisk in prerunning preparation?

Tags: files, data-recovery, testdisk

I want to recover a single file whose pathname  before it became lost I know. I am considering testdisk and photorec, and would like to know some differences between them, especially what I need to do before running them.

For testdisk, which I have tried a bit,

- Is it correct that it doesn't   require umounting the target partition or make it readonly?

  When I copy some gigabyte large virtual machine files out of the partition at the same time of testdisk's deep search, it is unusually slow or stalled. So I gave up. Does running testdisk (quick/deep) search prevent other program from accessing files on the same partition?
- Is it correct that it doesn't recover the files it find, but allows me to select one to recover?

For photorec, which I haven't tried,

- do I need to umount the partition or make it read only?
- Does it recover all the files (existing or deleted) during searching? Do I have to prepare a storage space large enough to store the xisting and pre-existing files on the partition?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it correct that it doesn't require umounting the target partition or make it readonly?

Yes, it's correct. umounting and making it read-only is always recommended because you must avoid writing anything on the filesystem that was holding the data. If you do, deleted
files may be overwritten by new ones.

> Does running testdisk (quick/deep) search prevent other program from accessing files on the same partition?

No, but it's a CPU intensive operation, so it would make your system slow.

> Does it recover all the files (existing or deleted) during searching?

As much as possible.

> Do I have to prepare a storage space large enough to store the existing and pre-existing files on the partition?

Definitely.